# Load Image to JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I want to load an image to JPanel. The images that are going to be drawn are images saved from this JPanel.

For example i have this picture that has been capture from the JPanel and later i want to load that image to the same JPanel.

[image]

I have tried this but it does not work. This piece of code is inside a class that extends JPanel. Any suggestions?

```
    public void load(String path) throws IOException {
       BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
       Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
       g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
       this.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You draw the image back to itself (?) using a Graphics object derived from the Image itself. Instead store the image to a field, not a local variable, and draw that image within the JPanel's paintComponent method. Most important, have a look at the [Swing graphics tutorials](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

```
private BufferedImage img;

public void load(String path) throws IOException {
       img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
       this.repaint();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (img != null) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: My paintComponent method handles other stuff. How can i draw the image outside the paintComponent? Sorry for the noobish questions i am new to swing

Comment: @ManosKontakis: you don't. Draw it inside of paintComponent. Please see my code edit, please read the tutorials.

Comment: Worked. Didnt thought of the if(img != null) solution. Thanks for your quick answer and your references!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by an override

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {...} for javax.swing components
and public void paint(Graphics g) for java.awt components